# openshift ssl edge termination risk

Tags: ssl, openshift

I have been reading the Openshift documentation for secured (SSL) routes.
Since I use a free plan, I can only have an "Edge Termination" route, meaning the SSL is ended when external requests reach the router, with contents being transmitted from the router to the internal service via HTTP.

Is this secure ? I mean, part of the information transmission is done via HTTP in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection between where the secure connection is terminated and your application which accepts the proxied plain HTTP request is all internal to the OpenShift cluster. It doesn't travel through any public network in the clear. Further, the way the software defined networking in OpenShift works, it is not possible for any other normal user to see that traffic, nor can applications running in other projects see the traffic.

The only people who might be able to see the traffic are administrators of the OpenShift cluster, but the same people could access your application container also. Any administrators of the system could access your application container even if using a pass through secure connection terminated with your application. So is the same situation as most managed hosting, where you rely on the administrators of the service to do the right thing.